# how to send MMS within my own application?

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I am working on a multimedia application. I am capturing one image through the camera and want to send that image with a text to some other number. But I am not getting how to send the image via the MMS.

Is there a way to send MMS within my own application and register listening for incoming MMS messages with a BroadcastReceiver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To send image as MMS after capturing, use following code inside `onActivityResult()` :

  ```
      Uri _uri=data.getData();

          Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
          sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, _uri);

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share"));
  ```